# Why torch.cuda.allocated_memory reports that GPU Memory usage was decreasing during forwarding?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, forwarding

I'm trying to record the CUDA GPU memory usage using the API `torch.cuda.memory_allocated`. The target I want to achieve is that I want to draw a diagram of GPU memory usage(in MB) during forwarding.

This is the `nn.Module` class I'm using that makes use of the class method `register_forward_hook` of `nn.Module` to get the memory usage before the forward method being called:

```py
class Segment(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 specs_truncated,
                 in_channels,
                 use_checkpoint=False,
                 use_batch_norm=True,
                 ):
        super().__init__()
        self.subspecs = specs_truncated
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.use_checkpoint = use_checkpoint
        self.use_batch_norm = use_batch_norm
        self.seq_of_nodes = self._make_sequential_by_specs_truncated()
        self.handles_forward_hooks = self._register_forward_hooks(
            [torch.nn.Conv2d, torch.nn.BatchNorm2d, torch.nn.ReLU, torch.nn.MaxPool2d],
            lambda d: lambda m, i:
                print("Memory allocated before execute {}-{}: {} MB".format(
                    d['name'], d['class'],
                    torch.cuda.memory_allocated()/1e6)),
            lambda d: lambda m, i, o:
                print("Memory allocated after execute {}-{}: {} MB".format(
                    d['name'], d['class'],
                    torch.cuda.memory_allocated()/1e6)),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.use_checkpoint:
            return checkpoint(self.seq_of_nodes, x, use_reentrant=False)
        return self.seq_of_nodes(x)

    def _make_sequential_by_specs_truncated(self):
        layers = []
        in_channels = self.in_channels
        for node_spec in self.subspecs:
            if node_spec == 'M':
                layers += [
                        torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),
                        ]
            else:
                layers += [
                        torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, node_spec, kernel_size=3, padding='same'),
                        ]
                layers += [
                        torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(node_spec),
                        torch.nn.ReLU(),
                        ][not self.use_batch_norm:]
                in_channels = node_spec

        return torch.nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def _register_forward_hooks(self, list_targets, pre_hook, post_hook):
        handles = {}
        for name, module in self.seq_of_nodes.named_modules():
            if isinstance(module, tuple(list_targets)):
                # handles[name + '.pre'] = module.register_forward_pre_hook(
                #    pre_hook({ 'name': name, 'class': module.__class__.__name__ }))
                handles[name + '.post'] = module.register_forward_hook(
                    post_hook({ 'name': name, 'class': module.__class__.__name__ }))
        return handles

    def deregister_forward_hooks(self):
        for handle in self.handles_forward_hooks.values():
            handle.remove()
```

But I got a very unintuitive result as I have described by the title:

```
Memory allocated after execute 0-Conv2d: 609.58208 MB
Memory allocated after execute 1-BatchNorm2d: 643.136512 MB
Memory allocated after execute 2-ReLU: 643.136512 MB
Memory allocated after execute 3-Conv2d: 643.136512 MB
Memory allocated after execute 4-BatchNorm2d: 643.136512 MB
Memory allocated after execute 5-ReLU: 643.136512 MB
Memory allocated after execute 6-MaxPool2d: 617.970688 MB
Memory allocated after execute 0-Conv2d: 601.193472 MB
Memory allocated after execute 1-BatchNorm2d: 617.970688 MB
Memory allocated after execute 2-ReLU: 617.970688 MB
Memory allocated after execute 3-Conv2d: 617.970688 MB
Memory allocated after execute 4-BatchNorm2d: 617.970688 MB
Memory allocated after execute 5-ReLU: 617.970688 MB
Memory allocated after execute 6-MaxPool2d: 605.912064 MB
Memory allocated after execute 0-Conv2d: 597.523456 MB
Memory allocated after execute 1-BatchNorm2d: 606.96064 MB
Memory allocated after execute 2-ReLU: 606.96064 MB
Memory allocated after execute 3-Conv2d: 606.96064 MB
Memory allocated after execute 4-BatchNorm2d: 606.96064 MB
Memory allocated after execute 5-ReLU: 606.96064 MB
Memory allocated after execute 6-Conv2d: 606.96064 MB
Memory allocated after execute 7-BatchNorm2d: 606.96064 MB
Memory allocated after execute 8-ReLU: 606.96064 MB
Memory allocated after execute 9-Conv2d: 606.96064 MB
Memory allocated after execute 10-BatchNorm2d: 606.96064 MB
Memory allocated after execute 11-ReLU: 606.96064 MB
Memory allocated after execute 12-MaxPool2d: 600.669184 MB
Memory allocated after execute 13-Conv2d: 595.426304 MB
Memory allocated after execute 14-BatchNorm2d: 597.523456 MB
Memory allocated after execute 15-ReLU: 597.523456 MB
Memory allocated after execute 16-Conv2d: 597.523456 MB
Memory allocated after execute 17-BatchNorm2d: 597.523456 MB
Memory allocated after execute 18-ReLU: 597.523456 MB
Memory allocated after execute 19-Conv2d: 597.523456 MB
Memory allocated after execute 20-BatchNorm2d: 597.523456 MB
Memory allocated after execute 21-ReLU: 597.523456 MB
Memory allocated after execute 22-Conv2d: 597.523456 MB
Memory allocated after execute 23-BatchNorm2d: 597.523456 MB
Memory allocated after execute 24-ReLU: 597.523456 MB
Memory allocated after execute 25-MaxPool2d: 594.377728 MB
Memory allocated after execute 26-Conv2d: 591.232 MB
Memory allocated after execute 27-BatchNorm2d: 591.232 MB
Memory allocated after execute 28-ReLU: 591.232 MB
Memory allocated after execute 29-Conv2d: 591.232 MB
Memory allocated after execute 30-BatchNorm2d: 591.232 MB
Memory allocated after execute 31-ReLU: 591.232 MB
Memory allocated after execute 32-Conv2d: 591.232 MB
Memory allocated after execute 33-BatchNorm2d: 591.232 MB
Memory allocated after execute 34-ReLU: 591.232 MB
Memory allocated after execute 35-Conv2d: 591.232 MB
Memory allocated after execute 36-BatchNorm2d: 591.232 MB
Memory allocated after execute 37-ReLU: 591.232 MB
```

As you can see, the memory usage reported by `allocated_memory` shows that GPU usage was decreasing!

Could anyone help me identify whether or not I might misuse any API in my code? Thanks